# When to call System.exit() on a cluster node?

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

When a node is down and therefore taken by a leader out of the cluster I would like the node itself to call System.exit().( I am using aka java)

How can the node surely know it has been removed from the cluster? 
How is the recommended way to do this? Are there any caveats to be aware of?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a milestone version of the upcomming Akka 2.4 you can register a callback via [`registerOnMemberRemoved`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4-M2/scala/cluster-usage.html#How_To_Cleanup_when_Member_is_Removed) method.

Comment: How stable is Akka 2.4 milestone? when will it become stable?